# adding Control to form but gap keeps doubling when added at Bottom of previous control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am adding controls to a form like this

```
Dim sharpUserX As New SharpUser()
Dim y As Integer = 0
For Each con As Control In PnlSharpUsers.Controls
    If TypeOf(con) is SharpUser then ' as i have the pnaddbtn, which i move to the bottom below
        If y < con.Bottom Then y = con.Bottom
    End If
Next
sharpUserX.Location = New Point(2, y)

'sharpUserX.Location = pnlAddBtn.location 'this does that exact same

sharpUserX.Size = sharpUserSize
PnlSharpUsers.Controls.Add(sharpUserX)
'put add button back on
pnlAddBtn.Location = New Point(pnlAddBtn.Left, sharpUserX.Bottom) 'strangely this is always correct
```

This is called on a button press, which adds a ShrpUser control to my panel, and then moves the addbtn panel to the bottom.

The add btn panel moves correctly, but the new control added gets added, but the location seems to double the difference of the gap from it to the previous control.

Heres the locations if i output them after each add

```
1 added
loc={X=2,Y=0} size={Width=849, Height=117}
2nd added
loc={X=2,Y=0} size={Width=849, Height=117}
loc={X=2,Y=135} size={Width=849, Height=117}
3rd added
loc={X=2,Y=0} size={Width=849, Height=117}
loc={X=2,Y=135} size={Width=849, Height=117}
loc={X=2,Y=291} size={Width=849, Height=117}
```

y on 2 should be 117 and y on 3 should be 234
the form does scale by font. Im thinking this is whats causing it, but i cant figure out what to do, and cant understand why the pnladdBtn works.

Comment: First snippet goes wrong because it doesn't adjust the location by the panel's AutoScrollPosition property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is more of a hack but it works.

```
sharpUserX.Size = sharpUserSize
PnlSharpUsers.Controls.Add(sharpUserX)
sharpUserX.Location = pnlAddBtn.Location
```

if i set the size before i add the control, then set the location after it seems to apply the font scaling to the size, but not the location, which works perfectly for me.